# EF6 write once to DB with FK relation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am wondering if it is possible to write once to the database on two objects where one object has a FK to the other.  For example lets say the DB structure is:

**C1**

```
public class Team {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
}

public class Player {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid TeamId {get; set;}
    public virtual Team Team {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have a class that will create players and teams.  At the moment I am doing it like this:

**C2**

```
public async Task<bool> CreateTeams(){
    var teams = new List<Teams>();

    while (i < 5){
        var team = new Team();
        teams.Add(team);
        //Assume Db is being instantiated somewhere else in the code
        Db.Teams.Add(team);
    }

    if(await Db.SaveChangesAsync() > 0){
        foreach(var team in teams){
            var player = new Player{
                player.TeamId = team.Id;
            }
            Db.Players.Add(player);
        }
        await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am making two DB calls to be able to create 5 teams with 1 player in each team.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of accomplishing.  Is it possible to do this with a single Database call, something like this possibly?

**C3**

```
public async Task<bool> CreateTeams(){
    while (i < 5){
        var team = new Team();
        //Assume Db is being instantiated somewhere else in the code
        Db.Teams.Add(team);
        Db.Players.Add(new Player {TeamId = team.Id});
    }

    await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Of course the above code doesn't work, hence why I am asking if it is possible somehow.  I am theorizing that if I assign the whole Team object it could possibly work?  For example:

**C4**

```
public async Task<bool> CreateTeams(){
    while (i < 5){
        var team = new Team();
        //Assume Db is being instantiated somewhere else in the code
        Db.Teams.Add(team);
        Db.Players.Add(new Player {Team = team});
    }

    await Db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Is what I am trying to do possible in any way?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but it's my understanding that the only time an actual write to the database happens is when `DB.SaveChangesAsync()` is called.

Comment: @Chizzle That is how I understand it as well, however the problem is that to generate an Id you have to write to a database.  So I am wondering if I can somehow create a player, and by creating the player I'll create a Team as well which will now get a generated Id, and that Id will be assigned to the player.  Reason being is that the above logic limits me greatly in a multi level structure, where I have to create everything at the top, write to DB, then create next level, write to Db, etc...  Its either that or write after each creation which is a huge hit to performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the primary benefits of EF (or any ORM) is that is does exactly that for you.  You can create arbitrarily large graphs of objects in memory and save them all to multiple tables with a single `SaveChanges()` call.

What you can't expect EF to do is to create a single SQL statement that will do all that, but while it will perform multiple SQL statements, only one `SaveChanges()` is needed.

This does depend on you setting up your persistence model correctly.  I can't see anything particularly wrong with yours (you could add a virtual collection of Player in Team, although I don't think that's required).

You example C4 should just work - does it not?

Comment: I edited my code and added C1-4.  Are you refering to C3?  If so, It does not work for me, it complains about a null Id every time.  hence where I have drawn my conclusion that you have to call save changes for the Ids to be generated.

Comment: I have not tested C4 as I am not home yet, I came up with that on the spot to try and give an idea of what I'm looking for.  Are you saying that my above pseudocode in C4 should just work the way it is?  Do I have to make any changes at all to it?  Assign the TeamId maybe?  In either case, could you post that as part of your answer so future visitors have a clear answer and I'll test when I get home in few hours and mark it as correct.

Comment: Your idea of what you'd like it to do corresponds exactly with what you should expect it to do. You should not have to assign the IDs yourself; EF will take care of that.

Comment: I see, I will test this when I get home and mark as correct then.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wait till it works before marking correct :)  I don't have VS in front of me to test your model; it's possible it requires a slight adjustment,  But even if so, the gist remains the same - you just reference the objects in memory and let EF do the heavy lifting.

Comment: with that in mind do I even have to write the TeamId line?  Is Virtual line of code enough to generate the FK?